# Handle apache camel consumer errors

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to stop route in case if user credentials changed, for this I want to handle `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.class` but this does not work:

```
from(_getImapSentURL(emailConfiguration)).routeId(routeIdSent)
            .onException(javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException.class)
            .process(new EmailErrorHandler()).end()
            .process(new EmailContentSentProcessor(user, filterSent));
```

and error processor

```
public class EmailErrorHandler implements Processor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        logger.info("handled");
    }
}
```

In console I'm getting this exception but it's not handled.

Where is the mistake?

**Solution:**

Add param to endpoint URL `consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true`

In route builder add exception handler

```
onException(Exception.class)
            .log("Exception occurred due: ${exception.message}")
            .bean(new EmailConsumerExceptionHandler(), "handleException").handled(true)
            .end();
```

Implement `ExceptionHandler`
Also if you set  `handle(..)` to true you can access to exception only in this way

```
Exception cause = originalExchange.getProperty(
            Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
```

in reffer to [Apache camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html)

Answer (score 3):

Its like a chicken and egg situation. The Camel error handler reacts when you have a valid message to route and then during routing some error happens.

But as the mail consumer cannot login then there is no valid message to route.

But you can turn on an option to bridge the consumer with Camels error handler. You can find more details from here: http://camel.apache.org/why-does-my-file-consumer-not-pick-up-the-file-and-how-do-i-let-the-file-consumer-use-the-camel-error-handler.html and the links it refers to